# Is acceleration of electron and speed of electron in a wire inversely related?

Tags: electrons, electric-current, acceleration, velocity, conductors

So we know that $${\vec{E}}= \rho{\vec{{J}}}$$ (where ${\vec{J}}$ is current density, and $\rho$ is resistivity).

and then, $${\vec{F}}= q{\vec{E}}$$ and $$q{\vec{E}}= m{\vec{a}}$$ so we can write ${\vec{a}} = q\rho{\vec{{J}}}/m$. But hold on, would *lower resistivity* mean *lower field* and *lower acceleration*?

Let's assume there is a cable wire.Then with a very low resistivity,electrons would travel in a very fast speed.However,with low resistivity,electron acceleration would be low.

How can I explain this contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a contradiction at all. It just means that the amount of time which is needed for the current to get going is higher. In the limit of the resistivity going to zero, the electron will interact less and less with the ions and therefore will need to accelerate way less. That being said, I can't say if this is observable, or if there are further effects making this one insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

In the classical model, the electrons are bouncing around in thermal equilibrium with the atoms of a conductor.  In the presence of an electric field, the path between each collision is curved in the direction of electron flow. The result is an average drift velocity down the wire which is proportional to the field.  A lower resistivity can result from a higher density of free electrons or from a longer mean free time between collisions (giving the acceleration more time to act after each collision).
In a wire of given length and applied voltage, the E field, and the acceleration, do not change if you change the material to one of lower resistivity; but the drift velocity and current may increase.